# Why does this expression not give me the expected result?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions

```
Expression<Func<BAL.Receipt, bool>> expKeyword = x => x.InvoiceNo.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text) | x.Alias.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text);
Expression<Func<BAL.Receipt, bool>> expFromDate = x => x.Date > dtpFrom.DateTime.Date;
Expression<Func<BAL.Receipt, bool>> expToDate = x => x.Date <= dtpTo.DateTime;

var ac = BAL.ApplicationInfo.db.Receipts.Where(expKeyword); 
if (dtpFrom.EditValue != null)
   ac.Where(expFromDate); 
if ( dtpTo.EditValue  != null ) 
   ac.Where(expToDate);
```

The expected result should return all the `Receipts` with a date is greater than `dtpFrom` date 
and less than `dtpToDate` and `txtSearch.Text` equal to `InvoiceNo` or `Alias`

Comment: What do you want to do? What result are you expecting?

Comment: The expected result should return all the Receipts which's date is greater than dtpFrom date and Less than dtpToDate and txtSearch.Textequal to InvoiceNo or Alias

Comment: And the actual results are?

Comment: The Actual result contains values that are less than dtpFrom.DateTime , which is not supposed to happen

Comment: if (dtpFrom.EditValue != null) -- is that true at run-time?

Comment: Also, see you say "dtpFrom.DateTime.Date", not "dtpFrom.DateTime"

Comment: Yes I know , Because I don't care about the Time , That's why I use dtpFrom.DateTime.Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not `ac.Where(expFromDate);`
But `ac=ac.Where(expFromDate);`

Comment: @DoobyInc firslty you say ac = /some expression/. Then you say ac = ac./some other expression/ and thus *appending* a new one. This is correct, try it.